# Can cpdf remove margins from PDF pages?

Tags: pdf, editing

To enhance the reading experience on e-readers, I'd like to crop the margins from PDF pages and maximize the text that's left, before converting them into PNGs.

Since it has "-mediabox",  "-cropbox", "-hard-box" options, it looks like [cpdf](https://community.coherentpdf.com/) is up to the job. Besides, it's available for Windows and as a CLI application.

But I can't figure out how to use it.

Would you have a working example?

Thank you.

[image]